# Mage.Cookies what for?

Tags: magento-1, cookie

We are thinking about removing the js.phtml from our template and I can't find a reason why not.

What is Mage.Cookies for and were is it used? Did I oversaw anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK it's used only in two places on CE:

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/cookienotice.phtml` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function allowSaveCookie() {
        Mage.Cookies.set('<?php echo Mage_Core_Helper_Cookie::IS_USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE; ?>', '<?php echo Mage::helper('core/cookie')->getAcceptedSaveCookiesWebsiteIds()?>', new Date(new Date().getTime() + <?php echo Mage::helper('core/cookie')->getCookieRestrictionLifetime() ?> * 1000));
        if (Mage.Cookies.get('<?php echo Mage_Core_Helper_Cookie::IS_USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE; ?>')) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            window.location.href = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('cms/index/noCookies')?>';
        }
    }
    $('notice-cookie-block').show();
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

And in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/pagecache/cookie.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lifetime = <?php echo Mage::helper('pagecache')->getNoCacheCookieLifetime(); ?>;
    var expireAt = Mage.Cookies.expires;
    if (lifetime > 0) {
        expireAt = new Date();
        expireAt.setTime(expireAt.getTime() + lifetime * 1000);
    }
    Mage.Cookies.set('<?php echo Mage_PageCache_Helper_Data::NO_CACHE_COOKIE; ?>', 1, expireAt);
</script>
```

I personnally use `Mage.Cookies` in some of my extensions so double check 3rd party modules too

Comment: that is what I found - but pagecache is not part of CE isn't it?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt templates are present in CE ;)